# php mysql search engine with commas and different tables

Tags: php, mysql, search

Table: Venta

```
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| Zona       | localidad     |  punto     | direccion     |
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| Santiago   | Quilicura     |  prueba1   | Casa Royal    |
| Santiago   | Tortal        |  test1     | Ferreteria    |
| Valparaiso |  Viña         |  asdf1     | Monitor       |
|Osorno      |  Queso        |  qwerty    | Listado       |
+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

I have this database in mysql, and I am conducting a search engine with php which qualifies depending on the search results.

This must admit commas, for example, if I search "Santiago, Quilicura" should leave the first line with all the information that is "Santiago, Quilicura, prueba1, Casa Royal"

This is my code

```
$value = $_POST['search'];
$value = explode(",", $value);

$values = $value[0];
$valor = $value[1];

print_r($value);
print_r($valor);

if($values != "" and $valor == ""){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT zona, localidad, punto, direccion FROM venta WHERE zona LIKE '%$values%' or localidad LIKE '%$values%' or punto LIKE '%$values%' or direccion LIKE '%$values%' ");
}
if($values != "" and $valor != ""){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT zona, localidad, punto, direccion FROM venta WHERE zona LIKE '%$values%' or localidad LIKE '%$values%' or punto LIKE '%$values%' or direccion LIKE '%$values%' AND localidad LIKE '%$valor%' or punto LIKE '%$valor%' or direccion LIKE '%$valor%'");
}   

<table>
        <th>Zona</th>
        <th>Localidad</th>
        <th>Punto de venta</th>
        <th>Direccion</th>
        <?php
        while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $zona = $run['zona'];   
        $localidad = $run['localidad'];
        $punto = $run['punto'];
        $direccion = $run['direccion'];
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$zona.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$localidad.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$punto.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$direccion.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }?>
    </table>
```

Which brings me if seeking "Santiago, Quilicura" are all the results that have "Santiago" and not specified with "Quilicura"

Someone can help me?

Comment: your columns  in the table `(City,locality,Address,Point)` are different from what you are requesting `(zona, localidad, punto, direccion)`  does your code work if no WHERE condition set?

Comment: `This must admit commas, for example, if I search "Santiago, Quilicura" should leave the first line with all the information that is "Santiago, Quilicura, test1, royal House"` is not true. first line in your table is `Santiago, Quilicura, prueba1, Casa Royal `

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, but is the same; city = zona; localidad=locality; punto = point; direccion = address

Comment: Will the order always be the same in the search?
For example, should "Santiago, Quilicura", "Quilicura,Santiago", "Quilicura, Casa Royal, Santiago" all produce the same match?

Comment: Exactly!! that's the idea

Comment: :-) it not Exactly - it is opposite :-) Order could be ANY

Comment: check @MikeBrant answer. that is exactly what are you looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a very good solution for you:

```
$value = $_POST['search'];
$value = explode(",", $value);
foreach($value as $key=>$val) {
   $value[$key] = trim($val);
}
$param = "'".implode("','",$value)."'"

$params = count($value);

if($params==0 || $params>4){
   echo 'Wrong number of search parameters!';
} else {

$query = mysql_query("
SELECT  `zona`, `localidad`, `punto`, `direccion` FROM (
  SELECT  `zona`, `localidad`, `punto`, `direccion`,
  zona in ($param) as m1,
  localidad in ($param) as m2,
  punto in ($param) as m3,
  direccion in ($param) as m4

   FROM `venta`) AS v WHERE v.m1+v.m2+v.m3+v.m4>=$params
");
}
```

and try to use PDO and bind_param  instead of mysql direct query

Comment: that's easy, but imagine if the user doesn't search by "localidad" and he into the input put "Santiago, Casa Royal"; "Casa Royal" isn't into localidad but is into "direccion", that's my problem

Comment: so my code works well, and now you want to search value in different columns?

Comment: That's what i need specifically

Comment: try my updated answer - you should just understand an idea. your select query string will become more and more complicated if you are trying to search in many columns different values. so for 3 values if user post - you will need add 9 rules like this one 
`OR ( C1 like V1 AND C2 like V2 AND C3 like V3)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into usinga boolean full text search for this sort of query.

That would take a query like this:

```
SELECT zona, localidad, punto, direccion
FROM venta 
WHERE MATCH (zona, localidad, punto, direccion)
AGAINST ('keyword1 keyword2 [...]' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

For more on full-text searches check out this link - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

You will be returned a list of matches with most relevant matches first.

Comment: that is cool! never met before full search commands. Have to learn that more!!

Comment: but I think it is still return different result than expected :-(  : `Which brings me if seeking "Santiago, Quilicura" are all the results that have "Santiago" and not specified with "Quilicura"`

Comment: mysql say what my table doesn't support full text :c

Comment: @EstebanVivancoPérez In older versions of MySQL you may need to use MyISAM table.

Comment: I've this version 5.5.40-36.1

Comment: I tried that sql in phpmyadmin and it works but not in the way of what I need :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write something that looks if something is inside a list:

```
SELECT zona, localidad, punto, direccion FROM venta 
WHERE 
  zona IN ('Santiago', 'Quilicura') or 
  localidad IN ('Santiago', 'Quilicura') or 
  punto IN ('Santiago', 'Quilicura') or
  direccion ('Santiago', 'Quilicura')
```

That's how your query would look like - the key is to transform your $_POST['search'] string into something that looks like an array inside a sql query.

This would mean that independently of what order the user inputs the search categories, you'd be able to find a match. The OR makes sure that even if the user only enters one of zona,localidad,punto, or direccion you still get a match.

So in php you'd have to do something like this:

```
$words = explode(",", $_POST['search']);

$sql_array = "('".$words[0]."'";
for($i=1;$i<count($words);$i++){
  $sql_array .= ",'".$words[$i]."'";
}
$sql_array .= ")";

$sql = "SELECT zona, localidad, punto, direccion FROM venta WHERE zona IN $sql_array or localidad IN $sql_array or punto IN $sql_array or direccion IN $sql_array";
```

}

Ok, after some discussion I suggest trying joins:

```
SELECT * FROM venta
JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM venta WHERE zona IN ('Santiago','Quilicura')) zonas ON zonas.zona = venta.zona
WHERE 
  venta.localidad IN ('Santiago','Quilicura')
```

Comment: that is almost the same what he has now : `Which brings me if seeking "Santiago, Quilicura" are all the results that have "Santiago" and not specified with "Quilicura"`

Comment: It's more that "Santiago", "Santiago, Quilicura", and "Tortal, test1" should all produce the same result. So LIKE won't work. 

"LIKE '%Tortal, test1%'" won't match anything.

Comment: Did you try hand coding the top sql query in something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes i did, but still brings me all the results, if I seach for ("Santiago, Casa Royal") the query brings me two rows when must be just one

Comment: Ok, I am starting to understand your questions better now. I think we need joins - I will edit my answer.